# CSS Positioning issue - right position works intermittently

Tags: css, browser, positioning

I've got an issue that is really bugging me: I wrote some css that works fine (as I expected) most of the time, however intermittently it doesn't. Looking further, it seems that the right property is not displayed every time. Here's the code:

```
input.search-lupe { 
position: relative; 
top: 318px; 
right: -915px; 
background: url(../images/lupe.png) no-repeat; 
width: 22; height: 23; border: 0; 
padding: 0 38px 0 10px; 
z-index: 201; }
```

Like I said, most of the time, it works as it should, however sometimes it doesn't and I can see that it is because of the right property is not being displayed every time. It seems very odd to me. Just to recap, when the element is displayed wrongly, I check the code in Firebug and that's what I see:

```
input.search-lupe { 
position: relative; 
top: 318px; 
background: url(../images/lupe.png) no-repeat; 
width: 22; height: 23; border: 0; 
padding: 0 38px 0 10px; 
z-index: 201; }
```

The issue happens in the same browser (Firefox 7, Mac sometime works, sometimes doesn't. The same with Safari 5 Mac). Any ideas?

Comment: Does it happen if you disable Javascript?

Comment: Intermittent issue?  Sounds like a dirty carburetor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's not your problem but shouldn't you add `px` after `width: 22; height: 23;`?

Comment: Thanks mate. It wasn't the px missing on width and height, but the px missing in the right property that was causing the problem. The above code was copied from Firebug but in my original code I didn't add the px it seems that all is working now.